# How to measure the maximum speed between 2 scripts linux that exchange a signal?

Tags: linux, bash, signals, posix, libc

I wrote two bash scripts that play ping pong by sending signals instead of
a ball. Measure (in number of exchanges per minute) the maximum speed reached
in the exchange.

Do you have idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Please add more detail to your question: What have you tried to solve your assignment? Where did you get stuck? Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I understand the first part of 2 signals, but I don't have idea how to solve the maximum speed!

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

Script are using the `trap` builtin to handle the signals, around so:

Script1:

```
#!/bin/bash
let a = 0

sighandler() {
  let a++
  if [ "$a" = 1000000 ]
  then
    date
    exit 0
  fi
  kill -SIGUSR1 "$pid2"
}

while true
do
     trap "sighandler" SIGUSR1;
done
```

Script2 is the same, but with "$pid2" instead pid1.

The important thing is: the signal handler sends the signal to the other process. The other process' signal handler does the same. Task done.

How could we share the pids of the tasks, well... it is another interesting question. Maybe temporary files would be a feasible solution.